# How can I fix the SQL Query error 'invalid column name'?

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am running the following query in VBA on a SQL server. In order to simplify I use an alias for the different columns in the select clause. VBA returns the following error:

> Invalid column name 'QtyDCo'.

I tried adding brackets and quotes, but it did not help. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix the error?

```
"SELECT Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colDate AS [Date], " & _
    " Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colClrBroker AS [Clr Broker], " & _
    " Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colAccount AS Account, " & _
    " tblDefProd.colInstr AS [FT/OP], tblDefProd.colCcy, " & _
    " Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colId AS Instrument,  tblDefDeriv.colExpiry, " & _
    " tblDefProd.colMultiplier AS Multiplier, " & _
    " IsNull(tblDatPositionsCalc.colLots,0) AS QtyDCo, " & _
    " IsNull(tblDatPositions.colLots,0) AS QtyBrk, " & _
    " QtyDCo - QtyBrk AS [Qty Diff], " & _
    " IsNull(tblDatPositions.colMktPrice,0) AS [Price(ETD)], " & _
    " IsNull(tblDatDeriv.colPrevClose,0) AS [Price(BBG)], " & _
    " [Price(ETD)]-[Price(BBG)] AS [Mkt Price Diff], " & _
    " Round(IsNull(tblDatPositionsCalc.colPrice,0),8) AS [Avg Price D&Co], " & _
    " IsNull(tblDatPositions.colPrice,0) AS [Avg Price Brk], " & _
    " Round([Avg Price D&Co]-[Avg Price Brk],5) AS [Avg Price Diff], " & _
    " IIf([Qty D&Co]=0,0,Round(IIf([FT/OP]='FT',tblDatPositionsCalc.colLots*tblDefProd.colMultiplier*([Price(ETD)]-[Avg Price D&Co]),IIf([FT/OP]='OP',tblDatPositionsCalc.colLots*tblDefProd.colMultiplier*IsNull([Price(ETD)],[Price(BBG)]),0)),2)) AS [Mkt Val D&Co], IsNull(tblDatPositions.colVarMar,0) AS [Mkt Val Brk], Round([Mkt Val D&Co]-[Mkt Val Brk],2) AS [Mkt Val Diff], " & _
    "Round(IIf([FT/OP]='OP',-[Qty D&Co]*[Multiplier]*[Avg Price D&Co],0),2) AS [Trade Val D&Co], Round(IIf([FT/OP]='OP',-[Qty Brk]*[Multiplier]*[Avg Price Brk],0),2) AS [Trade Val Brk], [Trade Val D&Co]-[Trade Val Brk] AS [Trade Val Diff], tblDatAdmFX.colSpot AS FX, " & _
    "Round([Mkt Val D&Co]*[FX],2) AS [Mkt Val CHF], Round([Trade Val D&Co]*[FX],2) AS [Trade Val CHF] " & _
    "FROM (((((" & MyQryPosComb & " AS Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined LEFT JOIN dbOps.dbo.tblDatPositions ON (Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colId = tblDatPositions.colId) " & _
    "AND (Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colAccount = tblDatPositions.colAccount) " & _
    "AND (Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colDate = tblDatPositions.colDate)) LEFT JOIN dbOps.dbo.tblDatPositionsCalc ON (Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colId = tblDatPositionsCalc.colId) " & _
    "AND (Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colAccount = tblDatPositionsCalc.colAccount) " & _
    "AND (Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colDate = tblDatPositionsCalc.colDate)) LEFT JOIN dbProd.dbo.tblDefDeriv ON Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colId = tblDefDeriv.colId) LEFT JOIN dbProd.dbo.tblDefProd ON tblDefDeriv.colProduct = tblDefProd.colProduct) LEFT JOIN dbMktData.dbo.tblDatDeriv ON (Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colDate = tblDatDeriv.colDate) " & _
    "AND (Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colId = tblDatDeriv.colId)) LEFT JOIN dbMktData.dbo.tblDatFX ON Qry_ETD_Pos_Combined.colDate = tblDatFX.colDate " & _
    "WHERE (tblDatFX.colCcy1=[tblDefProd].[colCcy] AND tblDatFX.colCcy2='CHF');"
```

Comment: You are not able to reference an alias in the select clause, try using a subquery or the columns itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use a subquery or [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175972.aspx) to first *define* the `QtyDCo` column and then in the outer/final query you can *reference* it.

SQL is defined such that all expressions in the `SELECT` clause are computed "as if" they're all computed in parallel<sup>1</sup>. As such, you can't reference a column that you're also *defining* in the same `SELECT` clause.

<sup>1</sup>As opposed to e.g. being defined as computed from left-to-right.